# Battlefield 3 elaborate chain of explosions

Tags: battlefield-3

I found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbSfUOuTF0w&feature=related) on youtube and trying to figure out how is this possible? How would you set up such an elaborate chain of explosions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of other videos that show more of the process and less of the... aftermath, this one for instance:

Back before it was patched (on 12/6/2011) AT mines were bugged and persisted for quite some time, so it was possible to have far more of them deployed.  I believe the patch changed the behavior so that you can only have 5 deployed at once now.

Of course, if mod tools and a mod scene emerge, it will probably be feasible to do this in-game again.

Comment: The patch also changed how long after your death mines persisted - rather than being there until they blew up, they now disappear after a few minutes